# Gamemaker vs Unity2d - Speed of Development

Tags: unity, game-maker

- I know coding, so programming is not a problem
- Money is not a problem at all, I can get both GameMaker Master
  Collection and Unity Pro

I want to make a 2d game.

So which one is better for speed of development? On which one would I be able to finish my project earlier?

Comment: Vlambeer often does 4-hour game prototypes using Game Maker to decide whether they want to do a game. That's fast.

Answer (score 7):

This fully depends on the developer at hand and how well the person knows the coding language. Assuming you can definitely do the art side of things, I'll go ahead and list some pros and cons of both engines.

Game Maker Studio:

Pros:

- Very, very fast prototyping.
- Very beginner-friendly coding language called GML.
- Extremely welcoming community.

Cons:

- The engine is by far more limited than Unity3D.
- You have to purchase all of the exports besides Windows.

Unity3D:

Pros:

- Incredibly large community. There are a crazy amount of tutorials to be seen/read.
- Very fast engine in terms of the language and in execution.
- Lots of staff support and an abundance of features.
- Many, MANY more platforms that you can release to without having to pay extra.

Cons:

- Overwhelming. Unity is very overwhelming for a lot of people.
- Takes a bit of time to get used to. The UI is difficult to get the hang of.
- The programming language is a little more difficult to get a grip on.

Game Maker Studio will get the job done sooner but Unity3D will get the job done better. Take your pick.

Comment: I would like to add that with the 2D utilities added to Unity lately, making 2D games has become significantly easier on this engine.